# Data truncation: Data too long for column 'sql_stmt' at row 1

Tags: java, mysql, mybatis

here is my xml code

```
<insert id="insertAnnualKiln" parameterType="list">
        insert into prm_annual_kiln (id,parent_id,runtime_kiln,runtimerate_kiln,shutdowntime_kiln,
        shutdowndesc_kiln,heat_clinker,elect_clinker,equip_code,prod_clinker_type) VALUES
        <foreach collection="list" item="item" separator=",">
            (#{item.id},#{item.parentId},#{item.runtimeKiln},#{item.runtimerateKiln},
            #{item.shutdowntimeKiln},#{item.shutdowndescKiln},#{item.heatClinker},#{item.electClinker}
            ,#{item.equipCode},#{item.prodClinkerType})
        </foreach>
    </insert>
```

the list have 36 elements,It was successed when I cutted the list to 10 elements,here is the error.

```
### SQL: insert into prm_annual_kiln (id,parent_id,runtime_kiln,runtimerate_kiln,shutdowntime_kiln,   shutdowndesc_kiln,heat_clinker,elect_clinker,equip_code,prod_clinker_type) VALUES         (?,?,?,?,    ?,?,?,?    ,?,?)    ,     (?,?,?,?,    ?,?,?,?    ,?,?)    ,     (?,?,?,?,    ?,?,?,?    ,?,?)    ,     (?,?,?,?,    ?,?,?,?    ,?,?)    ,     (?,?,?,?,    ?,?,?,?    ,?,?)    ,     (?,?,?,?,    ?,?,?,?    ,?,?)    ,     (?,?,?,?,    ?,?,?,?    ,?,?)    ,     (?,?,?,?,    ?,?,?,?    ,?,?)    ,     (?,?,?,?,    ?,?,?,?    ,?,?)    ,     (?,?,?,?,    ?,?,?,?    ,?,?)    ,     (?,?,?,?,    ?,?,?,?    ,?,?)    ,     (?,?,?,?,    ?,?,?,?    ,?,?)    ,     (?,?,?,?,    ?,?,?,?    ,?,?)    ,     (?,?,?,?,    ?,?,?,?    ,?,?)    ,     (?,?,?,?,    ?,?,?,?    ,?,?)    ,     (?,?,?,?,    ?,?,?,?    ,?,?)    ,     (?,?,?,?,    ?,?,?,?    ,?,?)    ,     (?,?,?,?,    ?,?,?,?    ,?,?)    ,     (?,?,?,?,    ?,?,?,?    ,?,?)    ,     (?,?,?,?,    ?,?,?,?    ,?,?)    ,     (?,?,?,?,    ?,?,?,?    ,?,?)    ,     (?,?,?,?,    ?,?,?,?    ,?,?)    ,     (?,?,?,?,    ?,?,?,?    ,?,?)    ,     (?,?,?,?,    ?,?,?,?    ,?,?)    ,     (?,?,?,?,    ?,?,?,?    ,?,?)    ,     (?,?,?,?,    ?,?,?,?    ,?,?)    ,     (?,?,?,?,    ?,?,?,?    ,?,?)    ,     (?,?,?,?,    ?,?,?,?    ,?,?)    ,     (?,?,?,?,    ?,?,?,?    ,?,?)    ,     (?,?,?,?,    ?,?,?,?    ,?,?)    ,     (?,?,?,?,    ?,?,?,?    ,?,?)    ,     (?,?,?,?,    ?,?,?,?    ,?,?)    ,     (?,?,?,?,    ?,?,?,?    ,?,?)    ,     (?,?,?,?,    ?,?,?,?    ,?,?)    ,     (?,?,?,?,    ?,?,?,?    ,?,?)    ,     (?,?,?,?,    ?,?,?,?    ,?,?)
### Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'sql_stmt' at row 1
; SQL []; Data truncation: Data too long for column 'sql_stmt' at row 1; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'sql_stmt' at row 1
```

Comment: how about ur table structure. the problem is u r trying to insert data than the column size.

Answer (score 0):

Change your column `sql_stmt` definition in your table to set a longer length. Such as:

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name> MODIFY sql_stmt VARCHAR(<a longer length>);
```

Comment: Do you have this column in other tables?